# Using Make for compiling C

Tags: c

I am trying to learn make to make my compiling easier as I learn C.

I am attempting to do:

```
gcc -Wall -g    3.c -o 3 -lm
```

using

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

clean:
        rm -f 3
```

but I don't know how and where to put -lm in the makefile. I've looked for tutorials online but they haven't specifically addressed the "-lm" option, or if they do it is without little explanation and doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: Is that not a flag for the compiler?

Comment: Yes, so I thought to append it to the CFLAGS line to get "CFLAGS = -Wall -g -lm", but I still got the same error where math.h was not included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "target" in which to execute the gcc command. Like:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

all:
    gcc -Wall -g 3.c -o 3 -lm

clean:
    rm -f 3
```

Then you can just replace parts of the "all" command, with your macros; CFLAGS, for example would probably have the "-lm".

It might help if you ran "make -n", that will tell you what make would do if it were to run.

Comment: pb2q's example is much cleaner - I just pasted your code. The way he shows it decouples the individual components, making it easier to maintain (compiler, linker flag, compile flags).

Comment: Funnily enough, your answer is the one that is actually working the best. All others are erroring

Answer (score 2):

Often you'll see library specific flags in a `LIBS` variable, e.g.:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -I/some/include/directory
LIBS = -lm -L/some/library/directory

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) 3.c -o 3
```

Comment: What does -I/some/include/directory, and -L/some/library/directory do? I think you may be overestimating my skill. I am a huge noob to not just C but also Linux-like-environments so I need a bit of babying in this area, sorry

Comment: @nebffa sorry just additional examples of things that might be used in those variables: `-I` adds a new directory to the _include_ search path, and `-L` adds a new directory to the _library_ search path, hence would usually belong in `$(LIBS)`, but you can ignore those arguments.

Comment: Ok sure thing, however even without -I and -L in your make file, it still errors telling me it can't find the reference to pow() and exp2(), so -lm is still not including the <math.h> header file? Man I really am a noob at this lol

Comment: Hi I have been able to make your makefile work for my purposes. Instead of $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) 3.c -o 3, I have instead used $(CC) $(CFLAGS) 3.c -o 3 $(LIBS) which works a treat. The compiler seems to want -lm at the end of the statement rather than in the middle. Thanks for your help and I've upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

The variable you are looking for is called `LDLFAGS`. From [§10.3 of the GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables):

> LDFLAGS
>
> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’.

So, simply do:

```
LDFLAGS += -lm
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This actually doesn't work - it returns the same error as before

Comment: ^_^ it still does not include the <math.h> header file, hence erroring at the use of pow() and exp2()

Comment: @nebffa: You have asked about one thing, expected to us to fix the error you haven't mentioned, and guess that you need a math.h header in your program that you haven't even shown :-) Be more specific!

Comment: Sorry Vlad, I am a huge noob to both C and Linux. I assumed that since compiling with -lm at the end included <math.h>, all I needed to do was get -lm into the make file somehow. Where am I going wrong here? Is my train of thought completely off track? Haha

Comment: @nebffa: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to compile and what error you are getting. Thus cannot really help you, sorry.

Comment: not sure how much I need to show you. Would you be willing to speak to me about it in chat?

Answer (score 0):

An extremely good tutorial:  [Make Tutorial: How-To Write A Makefile](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile)

and here is a good generic makefile I wrote:

http://pastebin.com/PCk0gNtE

The part that would most interest you would be this section:

```
# C Preprocessor Flags
CPPFLAGS +=
# compiler flags
CFLAGS += -ansi -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
# libraries to link to ( m == math )
program_LIBRARIES := m
# LDFLAGS is the variable to hold linker flags
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU make defines a lot of default rules. For C compilation and linking, those rules are:

n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.

n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

So the way to add "-lm" option to the linker is by defining:

```
LDLIBS = -lm
```

Then when you run make with your Makefile, you following commands will be run:

```
gcc -Wall -g -c 3.c
gcc 3.o -o 3 -lm
```

(note that make will compile your C program in 2 steps, first creating the object file 3.o then linking the object file into the executable 3)

(see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/ for the GNU make manual)